# rails parse date from mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I use Rails to connect to existing mysql DB from another project and I have error 'invalid date' when I select rows where date field has 0000-00-00 value. How I can avoid this error or tell Rails to use this field like a string?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear from the question when you're facing `ArgumentError: invalid date` error exactly (or rather doing what exactly). But the second part of your question it's pretty common:

```
def safe_date(date)
  Date.parse date
rescue ArgumentError
  date.to_s
end
```

The method passes argument to [Date#parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) method or returns string representation of the argument if a valid date object can not be created from it.

Comment: You should provide a description of what your code does so OP can understand/learn. Low quality answers may end up deleted.